# git error during commit: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: bash, git

Whenever I use `git commit -m "..."` with a message including spaces, it does not work:

**Input:**

`git commit -m "add latest dump"`

**Output:**

`error: pathspec 'latest' did not match any file(s) known to git`

`error: pathspec 'dump' did not match any file(s) known to git`

I am running these commands inside a bash environment. Copy and pasting the example input from above does not work. Using single quotes (') also does not work.

Comment: What environment are you running this in, with what shell? (e.g. bash/zsh/fish/PowerShell/cmd, Linux/BSD/Windows/WSL, ...) Normally the quotes would be interpreted by the shell and pass a single argument to the actual git command.

Comment: There's something very odd going on here with your terminal. What is the output of `man "foo bar"`, is it one line or two ([for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp2mx.png))? I think you'll need to do some investigating, from the info in the question it's not apparent what the problem could be.

Comment: Maybe you have some shell alias or function set up in place of the real "git" command, and it's not handling arguments properly when it passes them on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem does not occur anymore. I presume that some kind of faulty configuration from my web hosting provider was the root of this error.